# Easy part of Tate's theorem in finite group theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I would please need some help on the following question.

Let $G$ be a finite group.

$A^p(G)$ denotes the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/A^p(G)$ is an abelian $p-$group. 
$E^p(G)$ denotes the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/A^p(G)$ is an elementary abelian $p-$group.

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $G$ and $P\le H\le G$. Then $A^p(H)=A^p(G)\cap H$ implies that $E^p(H)=E^p(G)\cap H$.

Since we always have  $E^p(H)\le E^p(G)\cap H$ (easy check from the observations $G=HA^p(G)$ and $A^p(G)\le E^p(G)$), it suffices to show $E^p(H)\ge E^p(G)\cap H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P \le H$ we have $HA_p(G) = G$. So
$$G/A_p(G) = HA_p(G)/A_p(G) \cong H/H \cap A_p(G) = H/A_p(H).$$
Now $|G/E_p(G)| = p^r$, where $r$ is the number of cyclic direct factors of $G/A_p(G)$, so $|G/E_p(G)| = |H/E_p(H)|$.
Also
$$G/E_p(G) = HE_p(G)/E_p(G) \cong H/E_p(G) \cap H,$$
so $E_p(H)$ and $E_p(G) \cap H$ have the same order, and must be equal.

Comment: Thanks very much Derek. Very clear. Sometimes it is right in front of me... :-)